# How to get the next tag displayed after the given xpath location

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario, where I need to get the next tag name which is going to displayed after the given element locator.

Suppose in the following code, if i have xpath to the highlighted div tag and i want to get the tag name displayed next to it(Example "h1" here).

```
<body>
<div>
<img>
**<div>**
<h1>
```

Comment: i guess you can use `getAttribute("innerHTML")` with your current xpath

Answer (score 0):

Solution would depend on what it is:
if it is a sibling:

```
//div['xpath of your div']//following::h1
```

if it's a child:

```
//div['xpath of your div']//child::h1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div['xpath of your div']/following::*[1]"))
      .getTagName();
```